# Incorrectly listed as voting to close a question as duplicate

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52742364/i-need-some-help-getting-my-python-script-to-work) shows me as having marked the question as a duplicate but I did not: I vote to close the question as "too vague" not because it was a duplicate.

Comment: On linked Q: Jack, you really should not vote to re-open *before* fixing the question. If you believe linked question worth re-opening you should edited it in shape first. Inlining MCVE from a link is acceptable edit (also there is a good chance you'd have to work on actually creating MCVE out of OPs code).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: In my opinion the question, while it wants improvement, is fit for re-opening in its current form. Which is why I voted for that, while still asking for improvement.

Comment: @JackAidley so now there will be more eyes in re-open queue and it still does not fit "good question" definition as there is clearly no MCVE in the question. As result it will likely get more downvotes... unless more downvotes are your goal you may want to reconsider at which point to reopen.

Comment: Why does it say I voted to close as duplicate here? I voted to close as something else.